# How sum column values and format cell using conditional formatting?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I started to develop in React.js, and I'm using React-Bootstrap-Table.

1. I need to get the sum of the total of a particular column (updates on every change in search field).
2. I also want to add custom CSS for conditional formatting based on value     (example, if amount is less than average, need to be green
   text    if amount is near average yellow,    if amount is above
   average but less than maximum orange    else red).
3. Also number field needs to be right aligned

[image]

Code can be viewed here

```js
var DataTable = ReactDataComponents.DataTable;

// Generate random data
var names = ['201801003', '201801002', '201801004', '201801005', '201801006'];
var cities = ['2018', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017'];
var addresses = ['Travancore', 'Sivagangai', 'Pudhukottai', 'Madurai'];
var states = ['1200', '350', '6400', '1700', '750'];

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  data.push({
    id: i,
    name: names[~~(Math.random() * names.length)],
    city: cities[~~(Math.random() * cities.length)],
    address: addresses[~~(Math.random() * addresses.length)],
    state: states[~~(Math.random() * states.length)]
  });
}

var columns = [{
  title: 'CID',
  prop: 'name'
}, {
  title: 'Area',
  prop: 'city'
}, {
  title: 'Authority',
  prop: 'address'
}, {
  title: 'Amount',
  prop: 'state'
}];

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(DataTable, {
  className: 'container',
  keys: 'id',
  columns: columns,
  initialData: data,
  initialPageLength: 5,
  initialSortBy: {
    prop: 'city',
    order: 'descending'
  },
  pageLengthOptions: [5, 20, 50]
}), document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<title>React Table</title>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/carlosrocha/react-data-components/v1.0.0/css/table-twbs.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<body>
  <br>
  <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Area</H3>
  <br>
  <div id="root"></div><br>
  <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sum</H3>
  <br>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-data-components@1.0.1/dist/react-data-components.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css'></script>
</body>
```

Thank you

Comment: How can you except community to help you here without single line of code by just seeing your attached image

Comment: @Maju Your question is too broad currently. Are you asking for general advice? Or the solution to a specific problem? See SO's [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Once you clarify what you're looking for and add more context, we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

1. For every row you make, add it to a counter in your state
2. Do conditional css based on the value in the counter
3. Align it to the right with css